# Why does this basic main method while loop not work? no syntax errors

Tags: java, while-loop

-Ive cut out the main code as it seems unnecessary, the issue seems with this, The code runs once then even if i type 'yes' as an answer to the scanner, the loop stops. It only loops once.

```
String bool = "yes";
    while (bool == "yes") {
        int e1 = whichExam();
        printinfo(pp, csn, isa, fwt, lds, afl, oop, e1);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do you want to check another exam ('yes' or 'no')?");
        bool = scanner.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: It's hardly a duplicate, i didnt know what the issue was and if i knew i wouldn't have had to ask in the first place. If you judge duplicates like this a original question would be nigh on impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer:

you're comparing the `strings` incorrectly:

```
while (bool == "yes")
```

it should be:

```
while (bool.equals("yes"))
```

longer answer:

when you do  `while (bool == "yes")` you're checking whether both `String` *references* point to the same object in memory and because that is *not* the case *after* the condition is checked the first time, hence the loop only executes once. you might also want to use [`equalsIgnoreCase(String other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)).

Comment: ahh, works, ill accept answer when it lets me